# Problema con getUrlParameter('ID')

Tags: javascript

El problema que presento, es que tengo un sistema de ticket recien implementado, para poder ver los detalles del ticket, ocupo su ID, todo bien, puedo visualizarlo hasta que se generan los tickets que terminan en 8, por ejemplo, Se creo el Ticket 8, al querer visualizarlo, no me muestra nada de la informacion, en mi base de datos tiene tick_id 8, en la URL me lo muestra como 8, pero no me muestra nada de informacion, al crear y visualizar el ticket 18, me muestra el ticket 1, al crear el 28, me muestra el 2. Tengo el problema solo con los tickets que terminan en 8.

Ejemplo en la siguiente imagen.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si reviso el ticket 17, todo bien, me lo muestra tal cual. O el 19.

Agradeceria si me pueden orientar.

Anexo el console.log() de la imagen.

```
    var tick_id = getUrlParameter('ID');
    console.log(getUrlParameter('ID'));
```

Tengo este codigo mas abajo,

```
var getUrlParameter = function getUrlParameter(sParam){
    var sPageURL = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.substring(1)),
    sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('8'),
    sParameterName,
    i;
    for(i=0; i< sURLVariables.length; i++){
        sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');

        if (sParameterName[0] === sParam){
            return sParameterName[1] === undefined ? true : sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Puedes mostrat el metodo `getUrlParameter`?

Comment: Yo hice ese mismo sistema de tickets.  ¿ Podrias poner el getUrlParameter('ID') ?

Answer (score 1):

Ya vi mi error, en la parte:
sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('8'),
Puse 8 en lugar de &, ya modificandolo me cargo bien todo.

Muchas gracias de todas formas.